# Customize csh prompt based on uid/superuser status

Tags: linux, command-line, shell-script, freebsd, csh

I'm trying to set up a condition where my csh prompt is customized to change username color and prompt character if I take on root privileges via "su". What's the most sensible way of doing this?

Purely by eyeballing my existing .cshrc, I tried adding this but got "Illegal variable name". Is there a better way of checking user id and setting up an if/then against it, or another more sensible way of doing this altogether?

```
if ( $uid == 0 ) then

set prompt = "%{\033[31m%}${USER}%{\033[0m%}@%{\033[32m%}%m%{\033[0m%} %{\033[35m%}[%~]%{\033[0m%} # "
set promptchars = "%#"

else

set prompt = "%{\033[36m%}${USER}%{\033[0m%}@%{\033[32m%}%m%{\033[0m%} %{\033[35m%}[%~]%{\033[0m%} # "
set promptchars = "%$"

endif
```

Comment: What was the illegal variable name?

Comment: Does csh not use PS1, PS2, and PS3?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the prompt for root in Root's .cshrc

`/root/.cshrc`

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified I want to just use "su" to gain root privileges as a standard user, not "su -" to use root's whole login environment. Is it possible to have the shell track my user status in that case?

Comment: I am not sure. I use bash on Arch Linux. So my experience with csh is very limited. On my laptop if I `su` then I get the prompt I set in Root's .bashrc even though it isn't a login shell. If the behavior is different with csh then I don't have a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you *do* need to set the root prompt you want in ~root/.cshrc as the other responder sugggested, so you can get rid of the `if` construction altogether.  Besides that, your "illegal variable name" is caused by your `set promptchars = "%$"` - the "$" is being used to dereference a non-existent variable.  You *can* avoid that by using `set promptchars = '%$'`, but at this point, why?  That says you want '$' as a root prompt character rather than '#'.  Just get rid of that statement altogether.

Although not strictly necessary, you can also replace `${USER}` in your prompt with `%n`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the stock .cshrc that was set up in FreeNAS' default jail, so that promptchars line is what they had originally. Should I just comment it out?

As for adding the custom prompt to root's config file along with my own, that will still only work if I use "su -" as I mentioned to the other commenter and not just "su", right?

I'm specifically looking to have the prompt change when I gain superuser rights but don't enter root's login environment, meaning ~ still points to the home dir of my normal user, and so on. Not sure if I'm explaining myself well here, let me know.

Comment: I don't have familiarity with FreeNAS, but I use regular FreeBSD all the time, and also use `su` (not `su -`) all the time, and for me, the root prompt (after using `su`) is what is in ~root/.cshrc, not ~/.cshrc.  Is there a ~root/.cshrc, and if so, what does it contain for specifying a prompt?  But why not simply try it and see what happens.  (The fact that you're getting that "invalid variable name" message indicates there's something wrong with that promptchars specification.)

Comment: Well, apparently I've been trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist -- at some point I copied my user's .cshrc over to root's home dir so I would get the custom prompt with both accounts. That explains why I was getting the same prompt styling even after taking on root privileges, which I had just assumed was standard behavior. After differentiating root's config file with a different color, it changes the username color just like I wanted when I do a `su`. Sorry for the headache!